# TypeScript - override linter errors in vscode

Tags: typescript

I have a component that accepts a `justify` property. I have the `justify` property typed as:

```
type JustifyContent =
  | 'flex-end'
  | 'center'
  | 'space-between'
  | 'space-around'
  | 'space-evenly';
```

I omit `flex-start` because it is the default, and I'd like to be able to catch redundant properties like that. My problem is that if someone uses this component and passes `flex-start`:

```
<MyComponent justify="flex-start" /> // <-- error type "flex-start" is not assignable to....
```

That could potentially be a source of confusion. Is there any way at all that I can override that error message to say something like `flex-start is the default value of this property, you do not need to pass it`?

Comment: you can probably make a tslint rule to do this, but that seems like quite a bit of work. https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/ tslint can be used as a plugin when compiling TS, so it's warnings and errors will show up like any other TS warning or error. https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript-tslint-plugin

Comment: It's probably important to note that there is a difference between using a default, and providing the same value as a default. Defaults can change, if you use the default you're saying "I want to use the default, even if it changes in the future". If you provide the same value as the default you're saying "I want to use this value even if the default changes in the future". I don't think a developer mistakenly choosing the wrong option can be picked up by a linter, as the linter doesn't know the intent of the developer. This seems like something better solved by training and documentation.

Comment: yeah I considered a tslint rule but it's a lot of effort for a very minor problem (if you could even call it that). I think you raise a good point though, I do cover this in documentation already and explicitly disallow passing the default but you've given me something to consider so thanks